# about viewportFraction of PageView

Tags: flutter

I am using the viewportFraction of PageView, but it overflows because the width of the last element is different.
I want to put an add button on the last element, but I don't want it to be slidable.

```
Container(
      height: 96,
      child: PageView.builder(
          controller: PageController(
            viewportFraction: 0.6,
          ),
          itemCount: items.length,
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
            final isShowPlus = index == items.length - 1;
            return Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                buildItemCard(index),
                isShowPlus
                    ? Container(
                        margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20),
                        child: InkWell(
                            onTap: () {},
                            child: Container(
                                width: 37,
                                height: 37,
                                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                    image: DecorationImage(
                                        image:
                                            AssetImage("images/plus_icon.png"),
                                        fit: BoxFit.contain)))),
                      )
                    : SizedBox()
              ],
            );
          }),
    );
```

i want

[image]

Comment: Your question seems like it has been cut off. Can you complete the last sentence and also include the code you currenlt use?

Comment: @jraufeisen I have added the code, can you check it?